# Deprecated UI package in Meteor

Tags: meteor

As in meteor 0.9.1 they deprecated UI.insert, UI.render and UI.renderWithData, which is the best way to render a template and place it in the DOM? For example I have something like this:

```
UI.insert(UI.renderWithData(Template.comment_single, {comment: this}), $('#details')[0]);
```

So how can I change this deprecated implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You now use Blaze:

```
Blaze.renderWithData(Template.comment_single,
        {comment: this},
        $('#details')[0]
)
```

Please let me know if this works, having not tried it myself set. The migration guide is here:
https://meteor.hackpad.com/Blaze-changes-for-0.9.1-XHBsah1DhX1